# styled-components: extend styles and change element type

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Imagine I have the following styles:

```css
color: black;
border: 1px solid white;
```

and I want to apply them both to two elements of different types:

```
const SomeImg = styled.img`
  margin: 2em;
`;

const SomeDiv = styled.div`
  margin: 3em;
`;
```

How can I make both elements extend those styles?

---

It's easy enough if they were both `<div>` or `<img>`. I could do:

```
const ExtendMe = styled.div`
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
`;

const SomeDiv = styled(ExtendMe)`
  margin: 2em;
`;

const OtherDiv = styled(ExtendMe)`
  margin: 3em;
`;
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use prop "as" from styled-components who will change html tag of your component:
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop

Below an example of what you want:

```
const ExtendMe = styled.div`
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
`;

const SomeImg = styled(ExtendMe).attrs({
  as: "img"
})`
  margin: 2em;
`;


const SomeDiv = styled(ExtendMe)`
  margin: 3em;
`;
```

You can see on : https://codesandbox.io/embed/mj3j1xp6pj?fontsize=14